# Reactjs hook useState weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to display a list of Item from an API call to a list of components.

Here's my code:

```
function Content({...props}) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      return;
    }
    API.getInfo((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setComponents([])
      setList(data)
      console.log(data)
    })

  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (components.length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    let tmp = [...components];
    for (const elem in list)  {
      const info = list[elem]
      API.getUserById(info.userid, (data) => {
        tmp.push(<InfoItem id={info._id} key={info._id} info={info} module={info.module} since="N/A" user={data.initial ? data.initial : `${data.firstname} ${data.lastname}`} {...props}/>)
        setComponents(tmp)
        console.log(tmp)
      })
    }
  }, [list])

    console.log(components)

    return(
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <CardHeader title="My tittle"/>
                <div className ="col-lg-12">
                    {loading ?
                      <Card content={"Loading..."}/>
                    :
                      <Card content={
                        <div style={{height: "62vh", overflow: "hidden"}}>
                            <div className="list-group h-100" style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}>
                              {components ? components : <p>Nothing</p>}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }/>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see I use one useEffect to handle the result from the API and another one to update the components list. But when I display Content, it's always missing one or many item from the list, even when the list have only 2 elements. And when I display tmp, it's contain all the components as well as when I display the components list. I don't know why but it seems that the update of setComponents doesn't affect the return.

If I try to add some fake elements and fast reload, all the component are poping, I don't know how to force update the list component.

If someone know where that missing elements can came from it will be great. thank you.

Comment: You have this inside your loop, `setComponents(tmp)`. This will just update the component for a single item reach time, you will want to push all items inside the loop into an array and then call setState on that.

Comment: I would say using two useEffect callbacks here is a strange thing to do, your render requires the components, so just do everything in the one useEffect, otherwise your doing extra renders for no reason.

Comment: @Keith I'm agree with your first comment but I don't know how to wait for all components in tmp before use setComponents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the tmp array stay the same, even when new item are push so the setComponents doesn't render because it's still the same array, here's what I've done to fix that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      return;
    }
    API.getInfo((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      let all = []
      for (const elem in data)  {
        const info = data[elem]
        API.getUserById(info.patientid, (data) => {
          let tmp = [...all]
          tmp.push(<InfoItem id={info._id} key={info._id} info={info} module={info.module} since="N/A" patient={data.initial ? data.initial : `${data.firstname} ${data.lastname}`} {...props}/>)
          all.push(tmp[tmp.length - 1])
          setComponents(tmp)
          console.log(tmp)
        })
      }
      
    })

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for the async task to finish. Try to fit an `await` or a `.then` in the `API.getUserById`. Your data probably has not yet been retrieved by the time the `setComponents(tmp)` is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the anonymous function `(data) => {...}` in the `API.getUserById` is a callback call in `then` after the request so the data are well retreive before being push in tmp

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      return;
    }
    API.getInfo((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setComponents([])
      setList(data)
      console.log(data)
    })
  },[]);
```